# Hibernate - Join Tables Using Jointable

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 tables: Band, BandGenre, and Genre.

Right now, I'm getting Band to join on BandGenre, and BandGenre to join on Genre.  This seems like a bit much.  I've read in various places (including here) that Hibernate can figure out a join table, but I can't figure out how to do it.

So here are my hbm.xml files:

Band.hbm.xml

```
    <class name="com.myProject.hibernate.Band" table="Band">
        <id name="bandid">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name"/>
        <set name="bandGenres" lazy="false">
            <key column="bandid"/>
            <one-to-many class="com.myProject.hibernate.BandGenre"/>
        </set>
    </class>
```

BandGenre.hbm.xml (the jointable)

```
    <class name="com.myProject.hibernate.BandGenre" table="BandGenre">
        <id name="bandgenreid">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="bandid"/>
        <property name="genreid"/>
        <one-to-one name="genre" class="com.myProject.hibernate.Genre">
            <!-- the <formula> gets Hibernate to join Genre on BandGenre.genreid (rather than BandGenre.bandgenreid) -->
            <formula>genreid</formula>
        </one-to-one>
    </class>
```

Genre.hbm.xml

```
    <class name="com.myProject.hibernate.Genre" table="Genre">
        <id name="genreid">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="parentid"/>
        <property name="name"/>
    </class>
```

What do I do to get my Band to join directly to Genre (preferably so I can order by parentid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BandGenre as a [join table](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m) to join `Band` and `Genre` together like so.

```
<class name="com.myProject.hibernate.Band" table="Band">
    <id name="bandid">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name"/>
    <set name="genres" lazy="false" table="BandGenre">
        <key column="bandid"/>
        <many-to-many class="com.myProject.hibernate.Genre" column="genreid"/> <!-- add ' unique="true"' for a one-to-many relationship -->
    </set>
</class>
```

Just modify your `Band` POJO to have a list of `Genre`s instead of `BandGenre`s. Go ahead and ditch `BandGenre.hbm.xml`.

Comment: Using your code I get an error: "Could not parse mapping document from resource com/bandbrokers/hibernate/Band.hbm.xml" - ' Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "one-to-many".'

Of course, I have the "column" attribute set just like in your code.

Comment: I was using Hibernate 3.2, now upgraded to 3.6.5.Final and still getting the same error.

Comment: My bad. If a Band can really only have one Genre (as opposed to being in multiple Genres) then you have to have a `many-to-many` with `unique=true`. Answer modified.

Comment: Hmm... good point.. this is, in fact, a many-to-many relationship.  I should be getting back to this problem later today, and I'll post my results.

Comment: Yes!  My fault for not realizing this was a many-to-many relationship.  My thought process went "one band can have many genres" and stopped there.  I should've taken it further and thought "many bands can have the same genre".  It was obvious to you when I was using a join table, but call me newbish.  Thanks for the help!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, I used the solution above **without** the `unique=true` and everything worked perfectly.  Now I can get rid of all my BandGenre files!

Comment: Just digging into hib w/join tables myself so, glad to help. Modified the answer for future stumblers.